# how to make SuckEffect in silverlight C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, animation, expression-blend, expression-blend-4

How can I animate some object like `ListboxItem` when I click to start SuckEffect to go and hide to left corner of the screen, like deleting the item in the iphone.

I was trying to do easy animation to make the flying animation. but it doesn't work that way.

Comment: @O.D Ya, its an animation behavior in IOS, In iPhone when you delete some mail or images you can see that effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of skew, scale, translate & projection gives something similar (without the nice curves though). It moves fast so that helps:

[image]

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="ItSucks.MainPage"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="SuckLeft">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="0.05" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="0.05" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="248" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="-318" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="45" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="54" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="-35" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.SkewX)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FF1717C8" Margin="212,120,216,124" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="8" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Rectangle.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection/>
            </Rectangle.Projection>
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is just from Expression Blend authoring (best place to do this sort of thing as it is so interactive).

Comment: Thanks i was trying to do the same in blend, but doesnt work, the above storyboard works great !!